# File not found in windows 7 but it works in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows, getopt

I have written a Python script which is working on my Windows 10, but when I run the same code on Windows 7 with the same Python version (3.8), it doesn't find my input file:

Here is the piece of code:

```
# Get list of command line arguments, remove first argument
argumentList = sys.argv[1:]

# Options
options = "hai:s:"

# Long options
longOptions = ["Help", "project", "Input", "Sqo"]


try:
    # Parsing argument
    arguments, values = getopt.getopt(argumentList, options, longOptions)
    print("The arguments are : ", arguments)
    print("The values are", values)
    # checking each argument
    for currentArgument, currentValue in arguments:

        if currentArgument in ("-h", "--Help"):
            print("Convert Polyspace findings from JSON file to console in Visual Studio ccompliant format")
            print("Options:")
            print("  -i, --Input: JSON input file")
            print("  -s, --Sqo: SQO definition file")
            print("  -a, --project: Show results for all rules, even the ones not mandatory to fix")
            print("  -h, --Help : This help")

        elif currentArgument in ("-i", "--Input"):
            inputFile = currentValue
            print(inputFile)

        elif currentArgument in ("-s", "--Sqo"):
            sqoFile = currentValue
            print(sqoFile)

        elif currentArgument in ("-a", "--All"):
            product = currentValue
            print(product)

except getopt.error as err:
    # output error, and return with an error code
    print(str(err))
# read JSON data generated by Polyspace
try:
    with open(inputFile, "r") as readFile:
        data = json.load(readFile)
        sqoLevel = int(sqoRoot.get('level'))
...
except FileNotFoundError:
    print("Error: File not found " + inputFile)
    sys.exit(1)
```

I run in cmd line:

```
python PolyspaceReportGenerator.py -s polyspaceSqo.xml -i polyspaceResults.json -a XXX
```

in windows 10, everything is fine.
in windows 7, I get the following error:

```
    Error: File not found .\polyspaceResults.json
```

I even tried to create an absolute path:

```
    elif currentArgument in ("-i", "--Input"):
        inputFile = os.path.join("D:\\","Polyspace",currentValue)
        #inputFile = os.path.abspath(inputFile)
        print("The absolute path : ", inputFile)
```

But is still get the same error:

```
The absolute path :  D:\Polyspace\polyspaceResults.json
Error: File not found D:\Polyspace\polyspaceResults.json
```

Comment: Where is the `polyspaceResults_TUNSDK.json` coming from?

Comment: was a typo. I updated.

Comment: Is the `polyspaceResults.json` file in the current working directory in both Win 10 and 11? Why does the error message say .\polyspaceResults.json not found for a cmd line argument specified as polyspaceResults.json?